# ¿Como crear excel desde XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, excel

Actualmente tengo un reporteador en web que me genera algunos reportes en excel pero hay uno que es muy pesado generarlo y el usuario no puede filtrar el reporte ya que se ocupan todos los registros.
Quisiera saber como crear un excel pero desde xml, crear la estructura del excel desde xml y posteriormente pasarlo a excel , lo quiero hacer de esta forma ya que son una gran cantidad de registros de 300 mil a 400 mil, me podrían ayudar a como crearlo , que librerías es la que necesita etc.. o si hay alguna otra  manera de crear un excel con esa cantidad de registros. 
Actualmente lo hago creando un excel pero la mayoría de las veces me marca que se quedo sin memoria.

Comment: son mucha cantidad de registros, estas seguro que excel lo soporta ? Si desde el propio excel realizar una importacion de datos conectandola directo a la db u otro orgen de datos, puedes importar esa cantidad de datos correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Yo he usado la librería `SpreadSheetLight`, pero para esa cantidad de registros mi recomendación es crear un archivo CSV el cual abre de manera directa con Microsoft Excel, esto utilizando la clase `StringBuilder` y `CsvWriter`. La diferencia es tiempo es de 90% menos.

Comment: Como dice @CesarKrrillo un documento csv es lo mejor, pero tambien debes particionar los registros en varios archivos para generarlos de manera paralela habla con el usuario dile que su office se puede trabar al abrir un archivo tan grande.